# Sitecore SXA error illegal characters in path

Tags: sitecore8.2, sitecore-sxa

Any one have solution for this issue .
With Sitecore Solution without SXA Adding empty attribute to httpRunTime tag in web.config file >>  requestPathInvalidCharacters="", can fix issue special characters in URL and redirect you to "not found page" insted of 400 error page with message "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client()"

URL like : http://abc/* or http://abc/&  >>  redirect to item not found page and I replaced it with custom error page . So, NO issue with sitecore site without SXA.

I tried same solution with [sitecore SXA] site but not effected, It go to another error page with message >> illegal characters in path, Also I applied this solution https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/059908, But nothing effect, I still have the same error!!
Any solution, I looking for same behavior in SXA site

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using URl rewrite in IIS and created redirect rule to 404 page hosted in site core